# Radix Sort Crashing

Tags: c++, sorting, splice, radix-sort

I think I have my algorithm done correctly, but when it would crash when I run the code. I was wondering if I can use some of your eyes to see where I am making a mistake. I am suppose to create a Radix Sort to sort through the list.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <algorithm>
#include <list>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
void radixsort(list<int> s);
int find_max(list<int> t);
void splicing(list<int> s);
void radix_final(list<int> s, int maximum);

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    list<int>::iterator it;
    list<int> x;

    x.push_front(40);
    x.push_front(60);
    x.push_front(20);
    x.push_front(10);
    x.push_front(10);

    radixsort(x);
    for (it = x.begin(); it != x.end(); ++it)
    cout << ' ' << *it;
    cout << '\n';
    return 0;
}

void radixsort(list<int> s)
{
    int max = find_max(s);
    splicing(s);
    radix_final(s,max);

}

void radix_final(list<int> s, int maximum)
{
    list<int> list0;
    list<int> list1;
    const int MAX_ITERATOR = sizeof(maximum)*8;
    int divisor = 1;

    for(int i =0; i<MAX_ITERATOR;i++){
        if((s.front()/divisor)%2==0)
        {
            list0.push_back(s.front());
            s.pop_front();
        }
        else
        {
            list1.push_back(s.front());
            s.pop_front();
        }
        divisor = 2*divisor;
    }

    list<int>::iterator it;
    it = s.begin();
    s.splice(it,list1);
    s.splice(it,list0);
}

void splicing(list<int> s)
{
    list<int> even;
    list<int> odd;
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i<s.size();i++)
    {
        if(s.front()%2 ==0)
        {
            even.push_back(s.front());
            s.pop_front();
        }
        else
        {
            odd.push_back(s.front());
            s.pop_front();
        }
    } 
    list<int>::iterator it;
    it = s.begin();
    s.splice(it,odd);
    s.splice(it,even);
}

int find_max(list<int> t)
{
    int max = t.front();

    for(unsigned int i = 0; i<t.size();i++)
    {
        if (t.front() >= max)
        {
            max = t.front();
        }
        t.pop_front();
    }
    return max;
}
```

Comment: What did you observe when inspecting your code with the debugger?

Comment: it would step in at max = t.front(); then it would crash when I click next.

Comment: What are variable values before you _click next_?

Comment: it doesnt show any variable values.

Comment: I'm sure you can see what they are from your IDE.

Comment: @ThomasNguyen Why are you not checking to ensure the container is not empty before calling `front()`?

Comment: @ThomasNguyen Also you should pass the subject to sort by reference `void radixsort(list<int>& s)`. I'd suspect you're running into a stack overflow, since you don't match a ending condition for your recursive calls.

Comment: It looks like the issue is constant popping of values from the list. Eventually the list is exceeding the array. Or at least, from what I can tell from GDB this far

Comment: @ThomasNguyen I took the code and lo and behold, you are calling `front()` on an empty list here `if((s.front()/divisor)%2==0)`.

Comment: Oh I see now. I got it to stop crashing now. Thank you guys for all of the help. Now, its not sorting, so I will have to figure out what I am doing wrong here.

Answer (score 0):

```
void radix_final(list<int> s, int maximum)
{
  list<int> list0;
  list<int> list1;

  const int MAX_ITERATOR = sizeof(maximum)*8;
  //^^^ Eh?
  int divisor = 1;

    for(list<int>::iterator x = s.begin(); x != s.end(); ++x){
        if((*x/divisor)%2==0)
             list0.push_back(*x);
        else
            list1.push_back(*x);
        divisor = 2*divisor;
    }

    list<int>::iterator it;
    it = s.begin();
    s.splice(it,list1);
    s.splice(it,list0);
}

void splicing(list<int> s)
{
    list<int> even;
    list<int> odd;
    for(list<int>::iterator x = s.begin(); x != s.end(); ++x){
    if( ((*x)%2)  == 0)
       even.push_back(*x);
    else
        odd.push_back(*x);


  }
   list<int>::iterator it;
    it = s.begin();
    s.splice(it,odd);
    s.splice(it,even);
}

int find_max(list<int> t)
{
int max = t.front();
for(list<int>::iterator x = t.begin(); x != t.end(); ++x)
{
    if (*x >= max)
    {
        max = *x;
        }
    }
    return max;
}
```

Is the fixed version of your code. I don't know he algorithm to know what to expect; however I did track down the issue with the list causing the crash. It had to do with all of the popping off. Plus the max iterator made no sense to me.

Comment: You're making the same tactical error as the OP, and that is calling `t.front()` without checking for an empty list.  Your code may work, but calling`front` without a check is dangerous.

Comment: This is true; but my motif was to fix the crashing error he currently has. I assume since this is most likely a work in progress or in practice, that those logical steps in error checking and bug prevention along the way will be something that he later works on. As it sits prior, he has a crashing program in which couldn't further until he had resolved that. As it sits, his LOGIC sits mostly the same. Same with homework (even though this is not I assume), I suspect I shouldn't do the whole thing for him.

Comment: How do you check for an empty list while calling t.front(). I thought it wouldn't matter since i am physically putting things into the list? Or it stop from checking the list?

Comment: `size()` would be 0. Or my preferred method would be `<list>.begin() == <list>.end()` unless I am misunderstanding the question.